# About "unital partial magmas after n-multifunctors"

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

## Motivation

In Haskell, there are a bunch of so-called type classes that are theoretically "alike":

```
class Monoid m where
    mempty  :: m
    mappend :: m -> m -> m

class (Applicative f) => Alternative f where
    empty   :: f a
    (<|>)   :: f a -> f a -> f a

class Category c where
    id      :: c x x
    (.)     :: c y z -> c x y -> c x z
```

When I see such patterns, I like to know how they can be generalized. So I called these structures "associative *n*-coids" for the time being, and tried to find such structures for $n>2$.

## Definition

Just to be clear, I use the notation $X^n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) for $\underbrace{X \times X \times \cdots X}_n \}$.

$X^0 = \{ () \}$ is a bit of a special case.

### *0*-coid

A *0*-coid of $F:X^0\rightarrow Y$ equips $F$ with:

- a binary operation $\ast : F1 \times F1 \rightarrow F1$, and
- for every $A\in X^0$, an element $\epsilon_A \in F1$, such that $\epsilon_A$ is:

  - the left unit of $\left.\ast\right|_{F1 \times F1 \rightarrow F1}$, and
  - the right unit of $\left.\ast\right|_{F1 \times F1 \rightarrow F1}$.

### *1*-coid

A *1*-coid of $F:X^1\rightarrow Y$ equips $F$ with:

- a binary operation $\ast : FA \times FA \rightarrow FA$, and
- for every $A\in X$, an element $\epsilon_A \in FA$, such that $\epsilon_A$ is:

  - the left unit of $\left.\ast\right|_{FA \times FA \rightarrow FA}$, and
  - the right unit of $\left.\ast\right|_{FA \times FA \rightarrow FA}$.

### *2*-coid

A *2*-coid of $F:X^2\rightarrow Y$ equips $F$ with:

- a binary operation $\ast : FAB \times FBC \rightarrow FAC$, and
- for every $A\in X$, an element $\epsilon_A \in FAA$, such that $\epsilon_A$ is:

  - the left unit of $\left.\ast\right|_{FAA \times FAB \rightarrow FAB}$ for every $B\in X$, and
  - the right unit of $\left.\ast\right|_{FBA \times FAA \rightarrow FBA}$ for every $B\in X$.

## Questions, part 1

1. I'm unsure about my terminology. If you find any mistakes, please correct them :)
2. <strike>The difference between the definitions of *0*-coids and *1*-coids seems inelegant to me. Why does this happen? Is $X^0$ the culprit here? If so, have I over-generalized this structure?</strike>

   **-edit- I see what's going on now.** What I'm doing here is diagonalizing ($FAA$) after quantifying ($A\in X$). What I should be doing is quantifying ($FS$) after diagnoalizing ($S\in \delta X$).

   However, this would introduce a lot of clutter in the definition (I'd need to project the tuples to give the types for $\ast$). I'm only doing this to fit *0*-coids into the pattern, which seems like an bad justification. I think I have over-generalized this idea.

   Perhaps *0*-coids should only be noted as a special case of *1*-coids (cf. "Reductibility").
3. I assume a *0*-coid of $F$ forms a unital magma $(F1,\ast)$. Is this correct?
4. I assume an associative *2*-coid of $F$ is a category $C$, with $\text{Ob}(C)=X$, $\text{Hom}_C(A,B)=FAB$, $1_X = \epsilon_X$, and $f \circ g = g \ast f$. Is this correct?

## Reductibility

Any *0*-coid on $F:X^0 \rightarrow Y$ can be reduced to a *1*-coid on $F':(X^0)^1\rightarrow Y:(()) \mapsto F()$.

Any *1*-coid on $F:X^1 \rightarrow Y$ can be reduced to any *n*-coid on $F':X^n \rightarrow Y:A \mapsto FA\cdots{}A$.

## Questions, part 2

1. I can't come up with *n*-coids for $n>2$ that follows the pattern I've seen above. I suspect $n$ is limited by the arity of $\ast$. How can I rationalize this?
2. When I move to ternary *n*-coids, I can imagine definitions for *0*-coids, *1*-coids, and *3*-coids (with $\ast : F\underline{A}BC \times FB\underline{C}D \times FCD\underline{E} \rightarrow FACE$, underlining added for emphasis). However, I can't think of a definition for *2*-coids that follows the patterns. This leads me to believe that, for *k*-ary *n*-coids, only $n=0$, $n=1$ and $n=k$ make sense. Is this the case?
3. Is there an established name for *k*-ary *k*-coids?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to get at higher categories and multicategories.